# Remove label foreach

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have 4 labels with 4 answers. One andswer is correct. When I press a button I want that 2 answer to hide. So I have:

```
string[] possible_answers = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
string correct_answer= keyletter;
string[] wrong_answers= posibile_variante.Where(val => val != correct_answer ).ToArray();
```

and the labels

```
label_0
label_2
label_1
label_3
```

Assuming that the

```
label_0 = A
label_1 = B
label_2 = C
label_3 = D
```

How can I hide 2 wrong answers labels?

Comment: My results aren't showing `4 - 1 = 2`

Comment: @Jonesy Your calculator must be broken then.  Try another one.

Comment: Why should 4 - 1 = 2? I need to hide 2 answers from 3 wrong, what is hard to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a dictionary with your labels like

```
var labels = Dictionary<string, Label> { { "A", label_0 }, { "B", label_1 }, ... };
```

then on a button click as you say

```
foreach (var wa in wrong_answers)
    labels[wa].Visible = false;
```

Maybe it's not exactly like you need it, but you can get an idea from it.

Comment: Your idea with dictionary was perfect. Thank you. One more question please, what is the optim way to remove only 2 of 3 wrong answers? I incremented a i and verify with if(i < 2)  labels[wa].Visible = false;

Comment: There's so many ways to do it. For example `.Where(val => val != correct_answer ).Take(2).ToArray();` Then the loop will remove only first two wrong answers. If you want it random, you will have to do it another way.

Answer (score 0):

Threw together an over-elaborate example, with the assumption that you may want to change the number of possible answers for a given question. It dynamically sets the number of labels on the screen, based on the number of elements in possible_answers (`ResetLabels()`) and then randomly selects N (# Items displayed - Number to keep displayed) number of *wrong* answers to be removed from the screen `RemoveWrongLabels`. @Ondrej recommended using Take(2), but that statically selects the top 2 elements in the list (e.g. the user would know always know what the correct answer is from the remaining items). MSDN: [Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the **start** of a sequence.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 string[] possible_answers = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetLabels();

    }
    private void ResetLabels()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.labelContainer.Controls.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            this.labelContainer.Controls[i].Dispose();
        }
        this.labelContainer.Controls.Clear();
        for (int i = possible_answers.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Text = possible_answers[i];
            l.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            this.labelContainer.Controls.Add(l);
        }
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveWrongLabels(3, 2);
    }
    private void RemoveWrongLabels(int RightAnswer, int ItemsToDisplay)
    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        List<int> AnswersToHide = new List<int>();
        while (AnswersToHide.Count < labelContainer.Controls.Count - ItemsToDisplay)
        {
            int indexToHide = rand.Next(0, labelContainer.Controls.Count);
            if (!AnswersToHide.Contains(indexToHide) && labelContainer.Controls[indexToHide].Text != possible_answers[RightAnswer])
            {
                AnswersToHide.Add(indexToHide);
            }
        }


        foreach (var item in AnswersToHide)
        {
            this.labelContainer.Controls[item].Visible = false;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, nice example, I will try in few hours. Thank you